# Access denied exception when running a .Net 4.5 application published using VS

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-setup

I had a test build I was supposed to publish to the testing team. I used the default "Publish " option in visual studio to create an installer. It created the installer successfully, and application is getting installed.

But when running the application, it throws an error saying "Access Denied exception occurred" in "System.Deployment" class. I have no idea what is happening here, because my code is not even coming to picture here. It is just the default deployment tool's classes that are failing activation.

I have no idea where to begin troubleshooting this.

Edit:

http://pastebin.com/SFzJ562B Log file that is generated.

Comment: What is the message accompanying the exception?

Comment: No message. It just says, "Application could not be started. Kindly contact your vendor". In the log, this exception for system deployment class. Give me some time. I will paste the full log file here